# probability stat

Tags: probability

we consider the differential equation 
$$y'(t)=f(t,y(t)),\quad t \geq 0, y(0)=y_0$$

I haven't any idea, help me please.

Comment: Are you choosing the tags at random?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to further assume that $f$ is continuous.

Let
$$
\tilde M=\max_{(t,x)\in [0,T]\times [-M,M]} \lvert f(t,x)\rvert.
$$
Such $\tilde M<\infty$ exists due to continuity of $f$ in the compact $K=[0,T]\times [-M,M]$.

Let now $\{t_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}\subset [0,T)$, with $t_n\to T$. Since the sequence $\{y(t_n)\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is bounded then it has a convergent subsequence $\{y(t_{n_k})\}_{k\in\mathbb N}$, with $y(t_{n_k})\to \xi$.

Then for every $t\in [0,T)$ we have that
$$
y(t)-y(t_{n_k})=\int_{t_{n_k}}^t f\big(s,y(s)\big)\,ds, \tag{1}
$$
for every $t\in [0,T)$, and hence
$$
\big\lvert y(t)-y(t_{n_k})\big\rvert \le \int_t^{t_{n_k}} \big| \,f\big(s,y(s)\big)\big|\,ds\le \tilde M\lvert t-t_{n_k}\rvert. \tag{2}
$$
Letting $k\to\infty$ in $(2)$ we obtain 
$$
\big\lvert y(t)-\xi\big\rvert \le \tilde M\lvert t-T\rvert,
$$
which implies that
$$
\lim_{t\to T^-}y(t)=\xi.
$$
Extending now continuously $y$ to $[0,T]$, as $y(T)=\xi$, we obtain from $(1)$ that
$$
y(t)-y(T)=\int_T^t f\big(s,y(s)\big)\,ds,
$$
and hence $y'(T)=f\big(T,y(T)\big)$, which means that $y$ satisfies the IVP in $[0,T]$.

For the second question, according to Picard-Lindelof's Theorem, there exists a solution $\tilde y$ of the initial value problem
$$
x'=f(t,x),\quad y(T)=\xi, \tag{3}
$$
defined in an interval $(T-\tau,T+\tau)$. Lipschitz condition guarantees uniqueness, and as the previous solution $y$ satisfies $(3)$ in $[0,T]$, then $y$ and $\tilde y$ coincide in their common domain, and hence $\tilde y$ extends $y$ to a solution in $[0,T+\tau)$, and therefore $y$ extends, and its not a maximally defined solution.

Comment: I have two questions please:1- Where we use the fact that $f$ is Lipchitz relative the two variables $t$ and $y$?

Comment: This result does not require the satisfaction of Lipschitz condition for the second variable of $f$. Lipschitz condition is required for existence and uniqueness (Picard-Lindelof)

Comment: Why the author of the exercice tell that we suppose that $f$ is Lipschitz for thos variables to siplicity. Where the simplicity? We nedd the existence and unicity of solution here? Perhaps in the second questions? Can you see the edit of the problem please. There are an second question, we nedd to the condition of Lipschitz in this second question please?

Comment: Please what's the idea of this exercice? And why we need to suppose that $f$ is Lipschitz to the "two variables" not for $y$ only. Why we neef the hypothesis that $f$ is Lipschitz to $t$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The condition $\sup_{t\in[0,T[}|y(t)|\le M$ tells you that either the limit exists, or $y(t)$ oscillates really fast when approaching $T$. The Lipschitz condition tells you that $f$ cannot go from very positive to very negative too fast, and thus prevents fast oscillations.

Comment: I don't understand the second point: what the Lipschitz condition tells? If $f$ is Lipschitz relative to the two variables, then what's the consequence for $f$ and $y(t)$?

Comment: $f$ is Lipscitzienne for the two variables, then $$|y'(t)|\leq k|t||y(t)|$ then ?? i don't understand how we finish the proof